# Are questions about VHF antennas off-topic here?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions, specific-question, questions, stackexchange

I am not sure if this is a good place to ask technical questions—e.g.: power required to transmit data over [x]km—about VHF antennas; or if [electrical engineering](http://electronics.stackexchange.com) would be a better stackexchange site to ask on.

Where do you think would be best to ask?

Answer (score 2):

I believe it's a better fit for electrical engineering.

Answer (score 0):

Another option would be the [Amateur Radio](https://ham.stackexchange.com/) site. The intent is to be focused mostly on "ham" topics but, as their [site scope page](https://ham.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) explains, with some care most RF-related questions can be made relevant:

> Promoting understanding and skill in radio operation is a core mission of the Amateur service, so if questions about such services can be framed to be about radio in general, then they may be asked here.